# How to properly handle invalid bytes in UTF-8 strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I have a string with encoding ASCII-8BIT:

```
str = 'quindi \xE8 al \r\ngoverno'
```

I want to transcode it to UTF-8, for not having problems with char visualization.
Naturally, `\xE8` is not a valid sequence in UTF-8, so I get the error when I try to:

```
str.encode 'utf-8'
```

Which returns:

```
UndefinedConversionError "\xE8" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Reading the docs about encode method, and I came up with this solution:

```
encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
```

This way all the invalid sequences are replaced with the `?`. But if I want to display the proper char instead of the `?`. I have different escape sequences in this text, `\xE8`, `\xE0` ...

Is there a way to automatically replace them with the right escaped char?

Comment: What is the proper char, i.e. what's your expected output?

Comment: it is something like "è".

Answer (score 1):

Your string seems to be [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoded. This should work:

```
str = "quindi \xE8 al \r\ngoverno"

str.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
#=> "quindi è al \r\ngoverno"
```

Note that you have to use double quotes.

Comment: I have red about this. But my concern is, why it indicates me that is Ascii-8bit? And, I need to deal with lot of different encoded text ( I work on emails ), so this code will cause problems with all charset different from Iso-8859

Comment: @ciaoben emails usually contain a header specifying the encoding, something like `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"`. But any decent email library should be able to handle this for you. Don't reinvent the wheel ;-)